# Use rEFInd live usb values to fix Grub2

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader, refind

I have a machine that runs Ubuntu14.04 as it's main OS, but also has Windows8 and Slackware on it. Booting to the Grub2 menu allows for the selection of these OSes and several other options, but only the Ubuntu one works. I have tried several automatic grub recovery tools, but none seem to fix the issues.

I would have thought the drive was bad, but it reports being fine when I booted into a live GNU/Linux and looked at SMART values. Moreover, when I boot into rEFInd live, it finds the OSes AND can boot into them successfully. (IIRC the win8 one requires the shim? option to be run first)

Is there a way to get / export the rEFInd "script" or loading values, etc., from the live rEFInd and have it work on regular grub2 setup?